# How to integrate search option by using search autocomplete in drupal 7?

Tags: search

Currently i am creating a e-commerce drupal7 website . Tried integrating search autocomplete ,but i want to integrate search option in it, for example as in google search if we type the first three word like Tri it will show the rest option as trivandrum etc.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Which search you using? Search api?

Comment: Default search box,i.e we want to get the  data  in search box that is added through our created content type .